# Open new window on secondary monitor in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UWP project with two monitors that I want to use to open a new window on a secondary monitor. The application includes three parts:

1. Open Main Page on first monitor
2. Create new page
3. Open on secondary monitor

I wrote the first and second parts correctly, but I can't find a solution for the third part.

Please help me with moving the window to another monitor.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

      //called creat new page function
        NewWindow();
    }

    private async void NewWindow()
    {
        var myview = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
        int newid = 0;
        await myview.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Frame newframe = new Frame();
            newframe.Navigate(typeof(Newpage), null);

            Window.Current.Content = newframe;
            Window.Current.Activate();
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "Z";

            newid = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        });

        await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newid, ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum);

    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at the ProjectionManager class..

Comment: Is this a winforms app?

Comment: No, it's UWP app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and used [ProjectionManger Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.projectionmanager).

```
 private async void expand()
    {
        var NewWindow = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
        int Windowid = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        int NewWindowid = 0;

        await NewWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Frame newframe = new Frame();
            newframe.Navigate(typeof(Newpage), null);

            Window.Current.Content = newframe;
            Window.Current.Activate();
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "New Page";

            NewWindowid = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        });

        //Call ProjectionManager class for moving new window to secodary display
        bool available = ProjectionManager.ProjectionDisplayAvailable;

        ProjectionManager.ProjectionDisplayAvailableChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            available = ProjectionManager.ProjectionDisplayAvailable;
        };

        await ProjectionManager.StartProjectingAsync(NewWindowid, Windowid);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Ehssan's suggestion, the [ProjectionManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.projectionmanager) meets your requirement. When you create a new view, you could use [ProjectionManager.StartProjectingAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.projectionmanager.startprojectingasync#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ProjectionManager_StartProjectingAsync_System_Int32_System_Int32_) to send it to the projector or other secondary display.

You could see the official [Projection sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Projection) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This might help your for identifying monitors.

```
this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;
```

Comment: Screen class work in WFP platform, but i don't know how does it work in UWP.