# Winui 3 open a new window in secondary monitor

Tags: winui-3

I have a Winui 3 application. I need to open a new window in secondary monitor once user clicked on a button. I found below post which works for UWP.
[Open new window on secondary monitor in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53923498/open-new-window-on-secondary-monitor-in-uwp)
However this code is not working in Winui 3.

```
private async void NewWindow()
{
    var myview = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    int newid = 0;
    await myview.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Frame newframe = new Frame();
        newframe.Navigate(typeof(Newpage), null);

        Window.Current.Content = newframe;
        Window.Current.Activate();
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "Z";

        newid = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    });

    await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newid, ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum);

}
```

I am getting an error "System.InvalidOperationException: 'A method was called at an unexpected time." at `var myview = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();` line.

I did a lot of research but couldn't find anything related to display window in secondary monitor for winui 3. Please help me with displaying a window in another monitor with Winui 3.

Comment: Creating a new Window is easy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69235394/403671 and you can move that window using window.AppWindow.Move, ie: `window.AppWindow.Move(new Windows.Graphics.PointInt32(3000, 3000));`

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you for the comment. Actually I am struggling to figure out the secondary monitor position. Would you be able to help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UWP apps have only one windows while WinUI3 can create new ones. [How do I open a new Window in WinUI3 with WinRT/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231804/how-do-i-open-a-new-window-in-winui3-with-winrt-c/69235394#69235394).

Now,  to move the window to another screen, in theory, you should be able to use WinUI3's [DisplayArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.displayarea) class.

But the problem is its `FindAll` method is broken (for some time now...) as reported here; [Microsoft.UI.Windowing.DisplayArea.FindAll iterator throws "Invalid Cast](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6454)

There's also WinRT's [DisplayManager, DisplayTarget, etc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.display.core.displaymanager). but they're not super easy to use... And we can't use Winforms' `Screen` class...

So, one other solution is to use "classic" .NET interop, like this:

```
var window = new Window();
window.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "Hello" };
window.Activate();

var monitors = Monitor.All.ToArray();
if (monitors.Length > 1)
{
    var thisMonitor = Monitor.FromWindow(WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this));
    var otherMonitor = monitors.First(m => m.DeviceName != thisMonitor.DeviceName);
    // move to second display's upper left corner
    window.AppWindow.Move(new PointInt32(otherMonitor.WorkingArea.X, otherMonitor.WorkingArea.Y));
}
```

With this `Monitor` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Windows.Graphics;

public sealed class Monitor
{
    private Monitor(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Handle = handle;
        var mi = new MONITORINFOEX();
        mi.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(mi);
        if (!GetMonitorInfo(handle, ref mi))
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        DeviceName = mi.szDevice.ToString();
        Bounds = new RectInt32(mi.rcMonitor.left, mi.rcMonitor.top, mi.rcMonitor.right - mi.rcMonitor.left, mi.rcMonitor.bottom - mi.rcMonitor.top);
        WorkingArea = new RectInt32(mi.rcWork.left, mi.rcWork.top, mi.rcWork.right - mi.rcWork.left, mi.rcWork.bottom - mi.rcWork.top);
        IsPrimary = mi.dwFlags.HasFlag(MONITORINFOF.MONITORINFOF_PRIMARY);
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; }
    public RectInt32 WorkingArea { get; }
    public RectInt32 Bounds { get; }
    public string DeviceName { get; }

    public static IEnumerable<Monitor> All
    {
        get
        {
            var all = new List<Monitor>();
            EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, (m, h, rc, p) =>
            {
                all.Add(new Monitor(m));
                return true;
            }, IntPtr.Zero);
            return all;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() => DeviceName;
    public static IntPtr GetNearestFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd) => MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MFW.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
    public static IntPtr GetDesktopMonitorHandle() => GetNearestFromWindow(GetDesktopWindow());
    public static IntPtr GetShellMonitorHandle() => GetNearestFromWindow(GetShellWindow());
    public static Monitor FromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, MFW flags = MFW.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL)
    {
        var h = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, flags);
        return h != IntPtr.Zero ? new Monitor(h) : null;
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum MFW
    {
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL = 0x00000000,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 0x00000001,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002,
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum MONITORINFOF
    {
        MONITORINFOF_NONE = 0x00000000,
        MONITORINFOF_PRIMARY = 0x00000001,
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private struct MONITORINFOEX
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public RECT rcMonitor;
        public RECT rcWork;
        public MONITORINFOF dwFlags;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string szDevice;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    private delegate bool MonitorEnumProc(IntPtr monitor, IntPtr hdc, IntPtr lprcMonitor, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern bool EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr lprcClip, MonitorEnumProc lpfnEnum, IntPtr dwData);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, MFW flags);

    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hmonitor, ref MONITORINFOEX info);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!. This resolved my issues. However I had to do one modification. AppWindow is not directly available for window (window.AppWindow did not worked). I had to use Interop to get the appwindow like below.         
IntPtr hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
WindowId windowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
var appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);

Comment: @Chamal AppWindow as a property is available in latest WinAppSDK versions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.appwindow). Make sure you update the related nuget packages.