# MAUI CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher A method was called at an unexpected time

Tags: c#, .net, maui, winui-3

I'm trying to get the dispatcher of the main thread in the following way:

```
public partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }

    private async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var disp = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
    }
}
```

This yields the following error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WinRT.Runtime.dll
WinRT information: Could not create a new view because the main window has not yet been created
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WinRT.Runtime.dll but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: Could not create a new view because the main window has not yet been created
A method was called at an unexpected time.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I've tested, and confirmed that accessing WinUI's `CoreApplication.MainView` results in that error. Maui must not be compatible with that. Assuming your goal is to run code on UI thread, does this answer your question? [For Dotnet Maui, what the difference between Application.Current?.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async()) and MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74801284/for-dotnet-maui-what-the-difference-between-application-current-dispatcher-dis)

Comment: CoreApplication.MainView is only for UWP which has only 1 unique window. MAUI is based on WinUI3 which can have multiple windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76299400/winui-3-open-a-new-window-in-secondary-monitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WinUI 3, you should use the [DispatcherQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.dispatching.dispatcherqueue?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2).

This is an example based on the default MAUI project:

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
namespace MauiApp1;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        if (count == 1)
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
        else
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
    }

    private Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue? _dispatcherQueue;

    private async void OnAsyncClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dispatcherQueue ??= Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread();

        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                count++;
                
                _dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
                {
                    CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";
                    SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
                });

                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I’ve added a link to your answer, in my https://stackoverflow.com/a/74805342/199364. See `UPDATE DispatcherQueue…` (May be useful in some circumstances in Maui on winui3.)